# Order of Initialisation of Java-Objects

Tags: java, object, initialization

I just wanted to implement Objects in Java, called ***"Family"***. In its constructor, i want this objects linked to their neighbours, so when i create an ***Family***-Object, i need max. two other ***Family***-Objects.

```
public class Family {

    Family leftNeighbour;
    Family rightNeighbour;

    public Family(Family leftNeighbour, Family rightNeighbour) {
        this.leftNeighbour = leftNeighbour;
        this.rightNeighbour = rightNeighbour;
    }   
}
```

Now, i started to init three families:  `A` is the first, so it has only a right neighbour, `B` has two, `C` is the last, has only a left neighbour.

Problem:

```
Family A = new Family(null,B);
Family B = new Family(A,C);
Family C = new Family(B, null);
```

I can not init A, because B is not created yet. Also, i can not init B, because A is missing. Is there any possibility to solve this ***without*** getters and setters (find it a bit ugly, in case i need big amounts of family-objects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You could add this to the constructor:**

```
if (leftNeighbour != null)
  leftNeighbour.rightNeighbour = this;
if (rightNeighbour != null)
  rightNeighbour.leftNeighbour = this;
```

Then:

```
Family A = new Family(null, null);
Family B = new Family(A, null);
Family C = new Family(B, null);
```

But this is rather prone to mistakes.

**A better way - a "makeNeighbours" method:**

```
public class Family {
    Family leftNeighbour;
    Family rightNeighbour;

    public Family() {}

    public static makeNeighbours(Family leftNeighbour, Family rightNeighbour)
    {
        leftNeighbour.rightNeighbour = rightNeighbour;
        rightNeighbour.leftNeighbour = leftNeighbour;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Family A = new Family();
Family B = new Family();
Family C = new Family();
Family.makeNeighbours(A, B);
Family.makeNeighbours(B, C);
```

**A related alternative - have `makeNeighbours` take variable number of parameters**
(inspired by Ray Toal answer):

```
public static makeNeighbours(Family... families)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < families.length; i++)
   {
      families[i-1].rightNeighbour = families[i];
      families[i].leftNeighbour = families[i-1];
   }
}
```

Then:

```
Family A = new Family();
Family B = new Family();
Family C = new Family();
Family.makeNeighbours(A, B, C);
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I think the OP wants to avoid setters in order to make the objects immutable.  If the OP chimes in by saying the mutable family obejcts are okay, then it will be +1.

Comment: @RayToal probably not since OP hasn't marked the fields as `final`. Also, with current OP's design, it can't be achieved.

Comment: Heh, I mentally added the `private` in my quick read, as that's pretty much how the vast majority of Java classes usually are.  `private` is fine for immutability instead of `final`.  Okay then +1.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to make a public static method called `createSequenceOfFamilies` parameterized by a integer saying how many families you would like.  Inside that method, you can directly set the `leftNeighbour` and `rightNeighbour` fields.

That way you can avoid setters and leave your objects immutable.

Your call would be something like

```
Family a = Family.createSequenceOfFamilies(3);
```

Then what you call `b` would be `a.getRightNeighbour()` and your `c` becomes `b.getRightNeighbour()`.

Comment: From an extensibility point of view, I'm not sure this is a good idea. What if you want to add parameters in the constructor of Family? But this makes me think of having a `makeNeighbours(Family... families)` method, which seems like a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, agreed, your answer with `makeNeighbours` is the best approach. My answer comes with the cost of the clunky interface but it does allow the family objects to be immutable, so I think the answer is worth leaving here.

Answer (score 0):

To get your code to compile, you could do something like:

```
Family A = null;
Family B = null;
Family C = null;

A = new Family(null, B); 
B = new Family(A, C);
C = new Family(B, null);
```

But **you are still going to have to set the values with setters at some point**. Because you can't assign an object that hasn't been created. If you want avoid setters, you could create another method which wraps the setters, but you'll have to use them.

Comment: Changing the reference on `B` won't affect the fields on `A` nor `C` object references.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP wants.  A's fields are both null.

Comment: I know, but without using setters, that's about as good as it gets :) You can't insert objects and use them if they haven't been created

Comment: Lol... Again, I know. Which is why I said "You'll have to use setters at some point" :)